# Aggregation and populate using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two collection like this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var GradeSchema = new Schema({
gID: { type: Number, ref: 'User'},
grade: Number,
created_at: Date,
updated_at: Date,
type: Number
});

var Grade = mongoose.model('Grade', GradeSchema);
module.exports=Grade;
```

and:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
lastName:String,
uID: { type: Number,ref:'Grade' },
phone: String 
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports=User;
```

how can i first aggregate and then populate to have both collection information??

i used this command using $lookup in mongodb and it return my suggested documents:

```
db.grades.aggregate([{$lookup 
{from:"users",localField:"gID",foreignField:"uID",as: "result"}},{$match:
{"type":0}},{"$sort":{"grade":-1}}])
```

but when i used this in mongoose the "result" is [] and connection to user collection is failed:

```
Grade.aggregate([{"$lookup":
{"from":"User","localField":"gID","foreignField":"uID","as": "result"}},
{"$match":{"type":3}},{"$sort":{"grade":-1}}]).exec(function(err, data)
{console.log(data);});
```

Comment: `and connection to user collection is failed` what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean i cannot get desired result from "user" collection and read its data related to the  "gID"